# Spin the wheel only once a day in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

i recently implemented a wheel of fortune which spins and gives rewards just like it should.
But i want it only to spin once a day when the player touches the spin button.
At this state the player can spin it as often as he wants and get those rewards.
How can i implement that it can be only spun once a day?
I tried to save Date in PlayerPrefs etc. but everything failed?
Would appreciate if someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: What did you try? PlayerPrefs is one way to solve this issue. Also, what platforms is your game supporting?

Comment: I want to solve this problem using playerprefs.

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt want to hit enter wait a second

Comment: I am making a 2d game for android. I wanted to save the currentdate in playerprefs and when the next day begins the next date etc. the script should compare those 2 dates and if they are the same i will only be able to spin once and when they are not the same it makes them the same and i am again only able to spin once in this day. my english is kinda bad but i hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: If you could point me in the right direction how to go about it i would be really thankful.

Comment: Tried something like this?
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/672869/player-prefs-to-store-high-scores.html

Comment: Yeah i already have a working highscore system but dont know how this can solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Once per 24h:

Save DateTime.Now.Ticks (date in numeric-long value from year 0) as string in PlayerPrefs then long.Parse() it when u want to read it:

```
    bool ShowWheelToPlayer()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Ticks - TimeSpan.TicksPerDay > long.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastDateSpun", "0")))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void OnWheelSpun()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastDateSpun", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
    }
```

2. Once per day:

Save DateTime.Now in yyyy-MM-dd format. When we will read it - hours and minutes will be set to 0 so when comparing we just `.AddDays(1)` to it.

For example player spun wheel on `2017-07-08 12:31`, we will save `2017-07-08`. When comparing we will add to it one day: `2017-07-09` so player will be able spin wheel again when DateTime.Now reaches `2017-07-09 00:01`

```
    bool ShowWheelToPlayer()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now >
                DateTime.ParseExact(PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastDateSpun", "0000-00-00"), "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                .AddDays(1))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void OnWheelSpun()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastDateSpun", 
            DateTime.Now.Year + "-"
            + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "-"
            + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));

        Debug.Log(string.Format("Player spun wheel, saving date: {0}",
            PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastDateSpun")));
    }
```

This code: `PadLeft(2, '0')` makes sure that we save months and days using two digits (07 instead of 7). That way we keep our formatting: yyyy-MM-dd.

Replay to comment:

```
public void YourSpinMethod() //attach to button
{ 
    if( ShowWheelToPlayer() ) 
    { 
        //spin wheel code 
        OnWheelSpun(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I read this discussion: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/525604/doing-stuff-once-a-day.html but still dont know how to do this.

Comment: And i dont understand your code either. Could you please explain to me step by step how to do this? Of course only if you have the time to do this. I would appreciate it though.

Comment: Ayy it was wrong, added `- TimeSpan.TicksPerDay` so it will work once per 24h

Comment: where should i add this ?

Comment: Added 2nd option: once per day :)

Comment: Excuse if i sound kinda nooby but where in your code should i put my spinmethod?

Comment: I tried to add my spin method right before the first return true int your bool method but i cant call this bool method from a button

Comment: Thanks, but i get the error in the if statement: No overload method "ShowWheelToPlayer" takes 0 arguments :/

Comment: As a side note, most games use a "20" or "22" hour period rather than 24, as most players will not "Activate the Thing" at precisely the second it becomes available. If they consistently are 10 minutes late, then the availability drifts towards the evening, then past midnight, into the early hours of the morning, and so on (until the player skips a day).  So systems have a small "buffer" period so that the Thing is available during the time the player is usually playing (e.g. if they always play just after leaving work, then they'll consistently be Activating the Thing between 5pm and 6pm).

Comment: edited, forgot to remove "DateTime date" in method when i was testing it

Comment: Now it seems to work thanks. I can only use it once a day now. But what should i write in my reset script, so when i click my resetbutton it resets the playerprefs? for testing reasons

Comment: PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastDateSpun", "0000-00-00");